# Minimal polynomial question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

If I have an $n \times n$ matrix, all elements of which are defined over $\mathbb{Z}n$, and we have a min polynomial for this matrix, $p$. The coefficients of this polynomial are as follows: $a_0$, $a_1$,..$a_L$. $L$ is degree of the minimal polynomial. Can we safely assume all $a_0$, $a_1$,..$a_L$ <= m?

Comment: What is $m$ here?

Comment: If you mean $\mathbb{Z_m}$, then you can assume that all coefficients are in the interval from $0$ to $m-1$.

Comment: More generally, the minimal polynomial, by definition, has coefficients in the same field as your matrix.

Comment: Brian, read $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Answer (score 0):

The minimal polynomial of a matrix $M$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is the monic polynomial $p(x)$, with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$, of least degree satisfying $p(M)=0$.

So if your matrix has elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the minimal polynomial's coefficients are also elements of the same finite field. And of course you can represent every equivalence class $[a_i]=\{a_i + kp\,\vert\, k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ using an integer between $0$ and $p-1$ (or $1$ and $p$, if you prefer.)

Comment: Maybe it's assumed that we are working over a field, but it doesn't say that anywhere in the statement of the problem.